# Extract text between strings using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to extract from the text below the value next to `number` and the text in between.

**Text:**
`The conditions are:  number 1, the patient is allergic to dust, number next, the patient has bronchitis, number 4, The patient heart rate is high.`

From this text I want to extract the following values:

- `1, the patient is allergic to dust,`
- `next, the patient has bronchitis,`
- `4, The patient heart rate is high`

I have a pattern that allows me to get the value next to `number` and the first word of the sentence:

```
(numbers? (\d+|next)[,.]?\s?(\w+))
```

This is the result using `re.findall`

```
[('number 1, the', '1', 'the'),
 ('number next, the', 'next', 'the'),
 ('number 4, The', '4', 'The')]
```

As you can see, using groups I can extract the digit or `next` value from the text. But I have not been able to extract the entire sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `.` and `,` and the whitespace chars are optional after the digits or `next`, you might write the pattern with a non greedy dot asserting numbers again to the right or the end of the string.

```
\bnumbers? (\d+|next)[,.]?\s?(\w.*?)(?= numbers?\b|\.?$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgZyxn/1)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bnumbers? (\d+|next)[,.]?\s?(\w.*?)(?= numbers?\b|\.?$)"
 
s = "The conditions are: number 1, the patient is allergic to dust, number next, the patient has bronchitis, number 4, The patient heart rate is high."
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[
    ('1', 'the patient is allergic to dust,'),
    ('next', 'the patient has bronchitis,'),
    ('4', 'The patient heart rate is high')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/scbJJV/1)):

```py
import re

s = "The conditions are: number 1, the patient is allergic to dust, number next, the patient has bronchitis, number 4, The patient heart rate is high."

pat = re.compile(r"numbers? (\d+|next)[,.]?\s?([^[,.]+)")

print(pat.findall(s))
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ("1", "the patient is allergic to dust"),
    ("next", "the patient has bronchitis"),
    ("4", "The patient heart rate is high"),
]
```